# DSCL Mac GeneratedUID

Tags: macos

I have a macBook with snow leopard on it that I haven't used in a few months, and I have some videos that I want to recover from it... My problem is I forgot the password I set for it. My question is, does anyone know of any tutorials or can explain how to get the Password HASH using DSCL in single user mode? I've tried several different things that I've googled, and I'm just not familiar with macs as much.

So far, I've tried using 
dscl localhost -read /Search/Users/root | grep GeneratedUID | cut -c15-
to return the GUID, but it's returning with an error that the path isn't correct.. but isn't this path the most basic path for the GUID? I previously put windows on it as well using bootcamp, so maybe the path isn't correct because I have windows bootcamp enabled?

Comment: Have you tried replacing the string `root` with the account you want to recover? e.g. for me `dscl localhost -read /Search/Users/brandontilley | grep GeneratedUID | cut -c15-` (I will admit I'm not familiar with the info you're looking for, so this may likely be a dumb suggestion. :) Also, if you have low luck here, check out [http://apple.stackexchange.com/](http://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You could pull the disk and read it from another machine.

Comment: yes, i've tried using my own user name, like such: dscl localhost -read /Search/Users/JohnK and still gives me path not correct error.

Answer (score 0):

DirectoryService won't be running in single-user mode (or if it is, it'll be in a minimal localonly mode), so normal `dscl` commands won't always work.  Try this:

```
mount -uw /
dscl localonly -read /Local/Default/Users/yourusername GeneratedUID | cut -c15-
```

Then go look in //var/db/shadow/hash for a file named by your GeneratedUID, and it'll have the hashes (in hex).  I don't think the hash format has changed since v10.4, so the info [here](http://www.macshadows.com/kb/index.php?title=Mac_OS_X_password_hashes#Mac_OS_10.4_.27Tiger.27) and [here](http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2006/04/28/os_x_passwords_2/) (about halfway down) should still be relevant.